# PHP: How to implement exif_imagetype in this code

Tags: php, image, types, exif

Please take a look at this: http://phpbin.net/x/1841090478

Now I am trying to expand this code and add more checkers, like exif_imagetype() as you can see on line 139.

I cant get it to work, Im just receiving that exif_imagetype failed to open stream, no such... ( that the image doesnt exists ). I also tried $this->file->getName() inside the parameter, but still the same error.

Now I am questioning the whole thing. I cant see anywhere the image gets uploaded before it gets to the if($this->file->save .. but how can it retrieve pathinfo() then? And why wont ['dirname'].['basename'] to find the file not work? for the dirname i just get a . but the basename i get the correct image file name i am trying to upload.

So how does it work and where should i implement this exif_imagetype checker into this code?

Thank you in forward.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to implement this class?

Comment: I use this together with an ajax call request in javascript. Is that what you want to see? It's an javascript plugin and i only set the settings and where it should make an request to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick and dirty implementation for the XHR case (as discussed in the chat):

```
/**
 * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
 */
class qqUploadedFileXhr {
    protected $_tempFile; 

    public function __construct() {
        $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
        $this->_tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'xhr_upload_');
        file_put_contents($this->_tempFile, $input);
        fclose($input);
    }

    public function checkImageType() {
        switch(exif_imagetype( $this->_tempFile )) {
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {
        if (filesize($this->_tempFile) != $this->getSize()){           
            return false;
        }
        rename($this->_tempFile, $path);
        return true;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $_GET['qqfile'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])){
            return (int)$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];           
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Getting content length is not supported.');
        }     
    }
}
```